# Заполнение таблицы SQL

Tags: sql

Есть таблица Holiday с полями

```
Holiday ID-это первичный ключ,
TabelID-внешний ключ,
StartDate,
FinishDate
```

Заполняю таблицу данными так:

```
insert into Holiday(HolidayID,TabelID,StartDate,FinishedDate) values
(1000, 100, '2011-02-02', '2011-02-05') 
go
```

Ошибка такая:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Holiday_Sotrdnik". The conflict occurred in database "OtdelK", table "dbo.Sotrdnik", column 'TabelID'.

Как решить?

Comment: на будущее - гугл переводчик рулит :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заполнить сначала таблицу `Tabel`.

Comment: У меня нет такой таблицы.

Comment: тогда надо указывать, какая есть. откуда приходит ключ TabelId

Comment: Все, спасибо!!! Разобрались)

Comment: @wicS, не забудьте принять ответ.